# Как правильно сделать запрос UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет.

Мне необходимо одним запросом извлечь id из одной таблицы и обновить данные в другой используя его.

Таблица names:

```
id | name
----------------
1  | cat
```

Таблица products:

```
id | product | count
---------------------
1  | food    | 20
```

Зная имя, нужно взять id с таблицы names и используя его обновить count в таблице products. Помогите сделать запрос :(

Comment: Ну а сами Вы что поэтому поводу написали?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html Особое внимание на **Multiple-table syntax**. И последний пример.

Answer (score 1):

По сколько никто не дал мне ответа, пришлось копаться, разбираться. Вот решение:

```
UPDATE products AS t1 
INNER JOIN names AS t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id 
SET t1.count = НУЖНОЕ_КОЛ-ВО 
WHERE t2.name = ИМЯ_КОТА;
```

Comment: "...пришлось копаться, разбираться..." за это плюс, сразу так надо было делать. Форум создан для взаимопомощи, а не получения халявы. "... никто не дал мне ответа...", и не должны были, потому что в данном случае это означало сделать за Вас Вашу работу - Вам дали хорошую ссылку, а это и есть реальная помощь.